# Switching from Gas to Electric?

Tags: electrical, appliances, gas

We currently have a 4 burner gas hob, but we want to switch to the electric one to make cleaning easier.

Bearing in mind that our oven is already electric, what should be considered to make this change, and is it something I can do my self?

Comment: I find Gas cook tops much easier to clean than electric but it is personal preference I guess. Depending on local code this can be done by a home owner. The wiring and circuit breaker for the new Hob /cook top would need to be added. The wire size will be based on the current draw or demand. I wont try to give examples because we use wire gauge where I live and you use MM wire diameter from what I have read. Many stores will give advice on the wire size but be sure to check local code because sometimes free advise can be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK you would need to pay a professional to remove, or make safe, the gas pipework for the hob.

You would also need to pay an electrician to do the work if you need a new circuit for the new electric hob. Whether you need a new circuit depends on the diameter of the wires in the existing circuit and some prescribed ["diversity" calculations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq0uODypaGI) about the total loads.

On the whole, I'd pay someone else to do this and to certify it has been done to the appropriate mandatory standards.